# Using realloc() to increase size of array when even number is typed (from function)

Tags: c

hi im trying to make my array increase its size with realloc from function when even number is typed, but the compiler is displying Segmentation Fault whatever number I type.Any ideas how can i fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int MakeArray(int n,int *ptr)
{
    ptr = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        puts("Allocation failed");
    }
    return *ptr;
}


int ReAllocArray(int n,int *ptr)
{
    ptr = (int*) realloc(ptr,n*sizeof(int));
      if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        puts("Reallocation failed");
    }
    return *ptr;
}


int main() {
    int n;
    int *ptr=NULL;
    puts("Enter size of n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
MakeArray(n,ptr);
    puts("Entering even number is increasing the size of the array by 1");
    for(int i =0;i<n;++i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);
        if(ptr[i]%2==0)
        {
            ++n;
            ReAllocArray(n,ptr);
        }
    }
    puts("Your array is:");
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*ptr` is exactly equal to `ptr[0]`. So your functions doesn't return the "array", it only returns a single (uninitialized) element from it.

Comment: You also have to remember that arguments to functions are passed *by value*, which means the value in the call is copied into the functions local variable. All modifications to the local argument variables will be only to those variables. It seems you might need to take a couple of steps back to refresh your text-books chapters on pointers.

Comment: Test if allocation failed and halt processing immediately. In fact, 'n' is uninitialised in main()... Failing to satisfy the un-validated `scanf()` could result in `MakeArray()` trying to allocate several Gb worth of ints.... You've been here before. Don't leave variables uninitialised and ALWAYS TEST RETURN CODES!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass pointer to pointer to int to modify it or/and return the reference to the allocated memory

```
int *MakeArray(size_t n, int **ptr)
{
    if(ptr)
    {
        *ptr = malloc(n*sizeof(**ptr));
        if(!*ptr)
        {
            puts("Allocation failed");
        }
    }
    return *ptr;
}
```

Same when you realloc

```
int *ReAllocArray(size_t n, int **ptr)
{
    int *tmp = NULL;
    if(ptr)
    {
        tmp = realloc(*ptr,n * sizeof(**ptr));
        if(!tmp)
        {
            puts("Reallocation failed");
        }
        else
        {
            *ptr = tmp;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

When you call it you need to pass pointer to pointer:

```
MakeArray(n,&ptr);
ReAllocArray(n,&ptr);
```

It would be worth checking what those functions return to know if allocations succeeded.

Also:

1. Use the correct type for sizes (`size_t` nor `int`)
2. Do not cast the result of malloc/realloc. If it does not compiler you are using the wrong (C++) compiler to compile the C code.
3. Use objects not types in `sizeof`s
4. When `realloc` use a temporary variable. Otherwise, you may have a memory leak

BTW you do not need the `MakeArray` function at all as `realloc` will work fine when you pass NULL pointer (it will simple not copy any data to the allocated memory)